# Merging Y, Cr and Cb color components

Tags: python, image, image-processing

I have an RGB image , I converted it to YCbCr and showed each component separately

```
    #Read cover image
    cover_Image = Image.open('lena_color.png')
    #Convert cover image to YCbCr space
    ycbcr = cover_Image.convert('YCbCr')
    y, cb, cr = ycbcr.split()
```

I applied some modifications on the Cb component, now I want to merge the 3 components and convert them back to RGB.
I tried this to merge the 3 components :

```
   ycbcr = cv2.merge('YCbCr', (y,cb,cr))
```

but I got this error

```
    ycbcr = cv2.merge('YCbCr', (y,cb,cr))
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.5) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'merge'
> Overload resolution failed:
>  - Can't parse 'mv'. Sequence item with index 0 has a wrong type
>  - Can't parse 'mv'. Sequence item with index 0 has a wrong type
```

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga61f2f2bde4a0a0154b2333ea504fab1d), `mv` is the first parameter and is supposed to be a “vector of matrices to be merged”. In your code, the first argument is `’YCbCr’`. I cannot find any examples on the web that suggest that `’YCbCr’` is a valid argument to `cv2.merge()`.

Comment: Thank you. The problem is not with the 'YCbCr' argument, I found out that the 3 components are not of the same data type. So to be able to merge them I converted the Cb and Cr component to numpy.uint8, then used the merge method and it worked very well.